# How to get Expression for Nullable values ( fields ) without converting from Expression.Convert in C#?

Tags: c#, lambda, expression-trees, linq-expressions

I am dealing with the scanario of Nullable types during formation of dynamic query expressions. These expressions would fetch filtered data from any SQL Tables( interfacing with Code First classes using EF ).

I have normal object ( e.g Consignment operating on several properties along with Nullable properties).

My expression formation goes well untill I encounter some Nullable types. On these nullables, I am getting

> *The binary operator NotEqual is not defined for the types 'System.Nullable`1[System.Single]' and 'System.Single'.*

For removing this exception, I am using all appraoches regarding convertion posted on different threads.

[Invoking lambda expressions in Expression trees](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24456245/invoking-lambda-expressions-in-expression-trees)

[Trying to filter on a Nullable type using Expression Trees](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14637390/trying-to-filter-on-a-nullable-type-using-expression-trees)

These all are generating expressions with added word "Convert" ( i.e Convert(someValue) ) and in result I always have expression

```
t=>(t.Consignment.Id = 45000 && t.Consignment.someProperty>=45 Or t.Consignment.Weight! = Convert(5000)).
```

Of course I need the whole above expression WITHOUT "Convert". Because this "Convert" will not fetch the data from tables accordingly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! What should left to do? I already know conversion, but this makes the whole expression useless, because it won't project the records because of needless "Convert"

**Added**

```
   Expression NotEqual<T>(Expression PropertyType, ConstantExpression a_Constant, ParameterExpression parameter)
   {
    if(IsNullableType(Property.Type) &&!IsNullableType(a_Constant.Type))
    {
      var converted = a_Constant.Type != Property.Type ?  (Expression)Expression.Convert(a_Constant, Property.Type): (Expression)a_Constant;

     // here above statement returns (Convert(50000)) and all I want (50000), but i tried all combinitions from Expression in order to form this constant as expression, it always throws exception what I mentioned originally.

     var body = Expression.MakeBinary(ExpressionType.NotEqual, PropertyType,  converted);

    //MakeBinary statement returns {(t.Weight != Convert(5000000))} but I    need {(t.Weight != 5000000)}

     var expr = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, parameter);
     return expr;
    }
  }
```

**Code:**

```
public class Consignment
{
    public float? Weight { get; set; }
}    

public static class GenericQueryExpressionBuilder
{        
    private static Expression NotEqual<T>(Expression memberExpression, ConstantExpression a_Constant, ParameterExpression parameter)
    {
        ConstantExpression constantExpression = null;

        if (IsNullableType(memberExpression.Type) && !IsNullableType(a_Constant.Type))
        {                
             //var converted = a_Constant.Type != memberExpression.Type ? (Expression)Expression.Convert(a_Constant, memberExpression.Type) : (Expression)a_Constant;

           Expression constantExp =  Expression.Property(a_Constant,typeof(T),"Weight");

        **// above statement throws exception I commented.**

            var body = Expression.MakeBinary(ExpressionType.NotEqual, memberExpression, converted);

            //here I want "t=>(t.Weight!=5000.0) INSTEAD of t=>(t.Weight!=Convert(5000.0))"

            var expr = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, parameter);
            return expr;
        }

        else if (!IsNullableType(memberExpression.Type) && IsNullableType(a_Constant.Type))
            memberExpression = Expression.Convert(memberExpression, a_Constant.Type);

        return Expression.NotEqual(memberExpression, constantExpression);
    }

    static bool IsNullableType(Type t)
    {
        return t.IsGenericType && t.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>);
    }        

    private static Expression GetExpression<T>(ParameterExpression param, string a_strPropertyName, string Operator, object Value)
    {            
        MemberExpression member = Expression.Property(param, a_strPropertyName);
        ConstantExpression constant = Expression.Constant(Value);

        try
        {               
           return GenericQueryExpressionBuilder.NotEqual<T>(member, constant, param);             

        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException)
        {
            return null;
        }

        return null;
    }

    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> GetExpression<T>(Consignment consignment)
    {
        Expression expression = null;

        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "t");

        string PropertyName = "Weight";
        string Operation = "NotEqual";
        object Value = consignment.Weight;

        expression = GenericQueryExpressionBuilder.GetExpression<T>(parameter, PropertyName, Operation, Value);
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(expression, parameter);
    }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {


        Consignment consignment = new Consignment();
        consignment.Weight = 50000.0f;

        var deleg = GenericQueryExpressionBuilder.GetExpression<Consignment>(consignment).Compile();            

    }
   }
```

Comment: What do you want to happen if the value is null? And what *exactly* do you mean by "will not fetch the data from tables accordingly"? What does the generated SQL look like, and what do you need it to look like?

Comment: Jon Skeet : OF course, If the value is null, then it would be simply skipped.
I have a UI, where users entering their filters manually. These filters are then translated to form expressions. These expressions then apply on huge data set to get filtered records.

So, in my case, ther would be no filter that can contain nullable vlaue at all. But the data table mapped via code first operating on nullable fields

Comment: I don't see anything "of course" about that... there are definitely other options that could be equally valid. But it sounds like you want "(t.Consignment.Weight.HasValue && t.Consignment.Weight.Value != 5000)` or something like that. In other words, you can use the `HasValue` and `Value` properties to specify *exactly* what you want.

Comment: Right! , this is all I want.
but how to build that expression that can then be further concatenate with other expressions.

If(IsNullable(constantExpression)) { Expression.(property,constantExpression.Value) }... But this generates excpetion of the same wording, I posted in question.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not following you at this point. It would be a lot easier to help you if you could provide a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Jon Skeet : I edited my post, with code snippet and comments, hope it helps you to understand what I am looking for. In case still you miss something , please ask immediately.

Comment: Well I asked for a short but *complete* program. That's a snippet. I don't have time to take your snippet and work out what's required to convert it into a complete program - and then guess what you want the result to be. You should do that yourself, to save everyone else's time. (It would also help if you'd follow normal .NET naming conventions - you've got three different parameters, each with different approaches to naming, to start with!)

Comment: Jon : Would it be better if I send you small code file and client program?

Comment: No, absolutely not. The point of Stack Overflow is to create a knowledge base - solving your immediate problem is just a useful corollary. You should be able to pare this down to *just* the problem you're trying to solve, and demonstrate that in a short but complete program.

Comment: OK..I am working on it, and will post the whole on my orignal edited question.

Comment: Jon :I added my code with complete functionality to illustrate the idea.

all I want inside NotEqual method 

Expression.MakeBinary(ExpressionType.NotEqual, memberExpression, converted); should return t=>(t.Weight!=5000.0) instead of t=>(t.Weight!=Convert(5000.0))

Comment: But that wouldn't be a valid expression. It'll have to be `t => t.Weight.HasValue && t.Weight.Value != 5000`

Comment: ah Ok! if finally I am able to get all records if weight property containing some value ..
Not an issue, that valid expression would work then! So I need then          (t => t.Weight.HasValue && t.Weight.Value != 5000)

Comment: Right. So what have you tried in order to create that expression tree? You should just need to use `Expression.Property` and `Expression.AndAlso`...

Comment: Yes..I tried and it thrown exception : 

The property "System.Nullable`1 [System.Single] Weight" is not defined for the type "System.Single".
I edited my usage inside already listed code.

Comment: I see no sign of you trying to use the `Value` or `HasValue` properties. You're not calling `Expression.AndAlso` at all, and the only `Expression.Property` all is for `Expression.Property(param, a_strPropertyName)`. So I don't see how you've tried my suggestion...

Comment: Sir, Coudl you please help me how can I use Value and HasValue properties in order to form expression. Moreover, this is just single expression I want to have at the moment without using Convert. 

t=>(t.Weight!=50000.0) So, why should I use Expression.AndAlso? could help me about this?

Comment: You have to use `AndAlso` because you're converting it to `t => t.Weight.HasValue && t.Weight.Value != 5000` - which is what the C# compiler would basically do for you otherwise. I don't have time to fix your code right now, but I'll try to do so in a bit.

Comment: Ok, I would wait. but do you comment for a second, How at runtime Expression.. ( any method ) can convert t.Weight to t.Weight.HasValue??

Comment: See my answer. That's just getting the property from an expression, which you do with `Expression.Property`, which is why I said to use `Expression.Property`...

Comment: Simply look at what the C# compiler generates in a similar case and reproduce that structure.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's a short but complete example showing how to build the `c => c.Weight.HasValue && c.Weight.Value != 5000f` expression tree. I've removed a lot of irrelevant code from the question:

```
using System;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

public class Consignment
{
    public float? Weight { get; set; }
}    

public class Test
{        
    private static Expression NotEqual(Expression memberExpression,
                                       ConstantExpression constantToCompare)
    {
        // Other cases removed, for simplicity. This answer only demonstrates
        // how to handle c => c.Weight != 5000f.
        var hasValueExpression = Expression.Property(memberExpression, "HasValue");
        var valueExpression = Expression.Property(memberExpression, "Value");
        var notEqual = Expression.NotEqual(valueExpression, constantToCompare);
        return Expression.AndAlso(hasValueExpression, notEqual);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Consignment consignment = new Consignment();
        consignment.Weight = 50000.0f;

        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Consignment), "c");
        var weight = Expression.Property(parameter, "Weight");
        var constant = Expression.Constant(5000f, typeof(float));
        var weightNotEqualExpression = NotEqual(weight, constant);
        var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<Consignment, bool>>
            (weightNotEqualExpression, parameter);
        Console.WriteLine(lambda);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jon Skeet : It worked as I expected ! I had to do some hard coding in order to inform an exact type to Expression.Constant(ExpressionValie,tyepof(....)). But before I had to apply all checks of build in types ( float,string,int....).

Thanks for your time and all what you did!!

Comment: @Usman: If you've got a value (probably boxed) you can just call `GetType()` on that. Or make it generic in the constant type, and use `typeof(T)`.